# show another image on top of the background image inflex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have created a application with Background image using skin class. I want to show some images on top of the image in application. Can you please suggest how to do that in flex 4.
Code is here :

BackGroundImageskin:-

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableComponent")]
</fx:Metadata>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states> 
<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('Img/asianwoman.jpg')" left="0" right="0"  top="0" bottom="0" smooth="true"/>
```

Main application:-

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

        <s:Group visible="true">
            <mx:Image source="Img/News1.png" visible="true" />
            <s:Button label="My Button"/>
        </s:Group>
```

Here New1.png is not displaying and only background image displaying

Comment: Post the whole skin. I suspect you placed the contentGroup bellow the background image in the skin class.

Comment: No after the bitmapImage , skin class in closed. No contentGroup is added.

Comment: Your skin needs a contentGroup or it will not display any child elements. I would suggest copying the default skin and adding your background to that.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand it , can you please explain clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for your skin (assuming standard web Application):

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" alpha.disabled="0.5" alpha.disabledWithControlBar="0.5">

<fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 

    [HostComponent("spark.components.Application")]
]]>
</fx:Metadata>


<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
    <s:State name="normalWithControlBar" />
    <s:State name="disabledWithControlBar" />
</s:states>

<s:BitmapImage top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0" source="@Embed('img.jpg')" smooth="true" />

<s:Group top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" gap="0" />
    </s:layout>

    <!---
        @private
        Application Control Bar
    -->
    <s:Group id="topGroup" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" includeIn="normalWithControlBar, disabledWithControlBar">

        <!-- layer 0: control bar highlight -->
        <s:Rect top="0" left="0" bottom="1" right="0">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" />
                </s:LinearGradientStroke>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 1: control bar fill -->
        <s:Rect top="1" left="1" bottom="2" right="1">
            <s:fill>
                <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xEDEDED" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xCDCDCD" />
                </s:LinearGradient>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 2: control bar divider line -->
        <s:Rect height="1" left="0" bottom="0" right="0" alpha="0.55">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 3: control bar -->
        <!--- @copy spark.components.Application#controlBarGroup -->
        <s:Group id="controlBarGroup" top="1" left="0" bottom="1" right="0" minHeight="0" minWidth="0">
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout paddingBottom="7" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="7" gap="10" />
            </s:layout>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>

    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
    <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" />

</s:Group>

</s:Skin>
```

Comment: what is bgRectFill here ? which instance it is ? if it is id for <s:Rect> , color and alpha attributes properties are undefined.

Comment: Here if i click on a image, how it will go google.com website?

Comment: Wrap the BitMapImage in a group, add a click handler to the group, use navigateToUrl to go to the website.